# PHP: Aws\Api\DateTimeResult to String?

Tags: php, aws-sdk

The [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Api.DateTimeResult.html) for `Class DateTimeResult` include a function __toString():

> **Methods Summary**
>
> __toString ( )
>
> Serialize the DateTimeResult as an ISO 8601 date string.

I'm not familiar yet with that double-underscore notation. I've tried calling it using guesses at the correct syntax, e.g.:

```
$time = $myDateTimeResultObject->toString();
$time = $myDateTimeResultObject.toString();
```

...etc, but I haven't yet found the correct syntax.

What is the correct PHP syntax for calling `__toString()` on an object of type `DateTimeResult`?

Comment: Did you try `$myDateTimeResultObject->__toString()`?

Comment: `$string = (string)$dateObj;`; You don't call magic functions directly...

Comment: Any time the object is implicitly treated as a string (like `echo $obj`) or explicitly cast to a string (like `(string) $obj`) then the `__toString()` method will be called automatically.

Comment: That worked! Lars and Alex, if you would like to post your comments as answers, I will upvote both and mark one as accepted.

Comment: Both $myDateTimeResultObject->__toString() and $myDateTimeResultObject->jsonSerialize() will give you a string